Aussprache vom kurzen „e" vs kurzen "ä"
Ich habe vor kurzem ein Buch gekauft, Das neue sprechtechnische Übungsbuch, das von der deutschen Aussprache handelt.  In dem Buch wird behauptet, „Kurzes e und kurzes ä klingen gleich".  Laut dem Buch haben deshalb „Retter", „Wände", „necken" und „Blässe" den selben Klang (in Hinsicht auf den Vokal).
Stimmt das, oder ist das eine Vereinfachung?  Wenn es nicht stimmt, könnt ihr mit erklären, worin der Unterschied liegt?
(Übrigens finde ich das Buch nützlich,ob das stimmt oder nicht, weil es eine weitere Möglichkeit zur Übung bietet.  Ich würde ohnehin weitere Bücher bzw. Quellen zum Thema deutsche Aussprache begrüßen).

Ja, das stimmt und ist keine Vereinfachung. Kurzes "e" und kurzes "ä" werden in allen Dialekten des Standarddeutschen gleich ausgesprochen*. Es gibt keinen Unterschied in der Aussprache zwischen "Wende" und "Wände".
Kurzes "ä" existiert nur in Wörtern, die (scheinbar) von Wörtern mit kurzem "a" abgeleitet sind. "Wände" wird mit "ä" geschrieben, weil es die "Wand" gibt, "Wende" mit "e", weil es keine Form mit "a" von "wenden" gibt (auch wenn das etymologisch ein "ä" ist).
Z.B. wurde, um diese Regel durchzusetzen, die Schreibung von "Stängel" in der Rechtschreibreform von "Stengel" zu "Stängel" geändert, da es das Wort "Stange" gibt und "Stängel" davon die Verkleinerungsform ist. Das war natürlich nur möglich, da es von der Aussprache her keinen Unterschied gab.
*(Edit): In vielen allemannischen Dialekten gibt es eine Unterscheidung zwischen kurzen /ä/, Ausprache [æ] bis [ɛ], und kurzem /e/, Ausprache eher [e]. Es kann nun sein, dass Sprecher, vor allem in der Schweiz, diese Unterscheidung in ihr Standarddeutsch übernehmen. Das weiß ich nicht so genau, wer interessiert ist, stellt dazu am besten eine neue Frage. Diese Unterscheidung hat aber nichts mit der geschriebenen Unterscheidung zwischen "ä" und "e" zu tun, die wie gesagt, rein von der Vorhandenheit einer Form mit "a" abhängt.

Nur, daß "Stängel" nicht von "Stange" kommt, was ein kurzer Blick in den Kluge beweist. Aber (da es auch "rau" gibt") beräut man das eines Tages.

It might be worth mentioning that the similarity extends to the combinations "eu" and "äu". An example of "ä" being used when there is only an apparent derivation from a word with "a" is with "Wäsche" vs. "waschen". They have a common ancestor in the distant past, which is also an ancestor of the English "water", but the immediate predecessor of "Wäsche" is Middle High German "wesche" from Old High German "wesca". The situation is similar, but a bit more nuanced, with "Geräusch" vs. "rauschen".

@RDBury: the name for this phenomenon is called "Ablaut" (also in English) and this is commonly used to create "Kausativa/Faktitiva/Fientiva", e.g.: "rot" -> "röten" (to make red), "schwimmen" -> "schwemmen" (to make swim).

@bakunin Laut Kluge (25 Auflage) ist Stängel "Diminutiv zur Sippe von Stange". Und selbst wenn die Ableitung älter als ahd. ist, ist sie auch heute noch leicht diachronistisch als "Stange" + "-l" zu erkennen. Reue und rau dagegen sind nicht verwandt.

Kleiner Zusatz zum Thema [Kurzes "e" und kurzes "ä" werden in allen Dialekten des Standarddeutschen gleich ausgesprochen]: Im Schweizerischen Hochdeutsch gilt dies nicht! Oder zumindest spricht der Schweizer 'Wende' und 'Wände' anders aus, auch wenn er Hochdeutsch spricht. Dasselbe bei anderen Beispielen, die mir einfallen, z.B. resonieren/räsonieren, Stengel/Stängel

Genauer gesagt sprechen wir Schweizer das kurze E genau gleich aus wie das lange E, einfach kürzer. Ehrlich gesagt fällt mir gerade auf, dass dies aber inkonsistent ist. Zum Beispiel beim Wort "begehren" spreche ich die ersten zwei E's als "E", das letzte eher als "Ä", owbohl nur das mittlere E lang (und betont) ist. Aber beim Wort "verehren" ist auch das erste E ein "Ä". Ach die schweizer sind so komisch. Am besten wir lassen die Schweiz für diese Frage mal aussen vor..

Der Unterschied existiert auch im Schwäbischen und korreliert interessanterweise nicht mit der Rechtschreibung. Der erste Vokal in „Retter" und „Wände" wird im Schwäbischen als E gesprochen, der in „necken" und „Blässe" als Ä.

@Dodezv: Dein Kommentar zur Schweizer Aussprache ist missverständlich. Man könnte meinen, es ginge um die schweizerdeutschen Dialekte, obwohl es tatsächlich ums Schweizer Hochdeutsch bzw. Standarddeutsch geht. Vereinfachend könntest du auch sagen: «In der Schweiz …».

Die Antwort von Dodezv ist vollkommen korrekt, vor allem, weil in der Frage die langen Vokale kein Thema waren. Trotzdem möchte ich ergänzen, dass es in den Regionen, in denen bairische Dialekte vorherrschen, vor allem aber in Österreich, auch bei den langen Vokalen keinen Unterschied gibt. Die folgenden beiden Sätze klingen in der österreichischen Aussprache von Standarddeutsch genau gleich:

Im Wald sind viele Beeren. (In D [ˈbeːɐn̩] oder [ˈbeːʁən], in Ö: [ˈbe̞ːɐn̩])
Im Wald sind viele Bären. (In D: [ˈbɛːɐn̩] oder [ˈbɛːʁən], in Ö: [ˈbe̞ːɐn̩])

